# How can I protect my 'key.json' file from being updated on Github?

Tags: json, github

I have some API keys for our team.

And I'd like to protect the `key.json` file which includes all API keys in it. But still as other users might need this `key.json` to run codes, I want to upload to Github but I also want this file not to be updated. Here's what I want.

**1. Make public `key.json` file**

At `key.json` file:

```json
{
    "API_KEY": "Your API Key",
    "APP_ID": "Your App ID"
}
```

**2. Push this file to Github repo**

**3. Update `key.json` file**

At `key.json` file:

```json
{
    "API_KEY": "abc123",
    "APP_ID": "efg456"
}
```

**4. Make `.gitignore` and add `key.json` file**

At `.gitignore` file:

```
key.json
```

And then I pushed this file, but it was updated as **3.**

Could you guys help me with this? And also any other better ways to protect this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the API keys are secret informations, then you should not make them public.**

1. Make a `key.json.sample` which only contain the dummy keys. Put this file into git repo.
2. Include `key.json` in `.gitignore`.
3. Manage and share the real api keys with your team in other place.

Comment: Oh I thought I didn't fully understand git commands and options.. I'll make sample file!! thank you so much!